# how can i make an event handler on datagrid in c#.net that can open a different page upon clicking any data item on that grid

Tags: c#, .net, oracle

```
namespace WpfApplication2
{    
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        private OracleConnection conn = new OracleConnection();
        private OracleCommand cmd;
        private OracleDataAdapter da;
        private OracleCommandBuilder cb;
        private DataSet1 dg;

        private void connect_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {

         conn.ConnectionString = "Data Source = orcl; User Id =HR;Password= HR;";
            try
            {
                conn.Open();

                string sql = "select * from inventory";
                cmd = new OracleCommand(sql, conn);
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;

                da = new OracleDataAdapter(cmd);
                cb = new OracleCommandBuilder(da);
                dg = new DataSet1();
                da.Fill(dg);

                dataGrid.ItemsSource = dg.Tables[1].DefaultView;
            }catch(OracleException ex)
            {
                switch (ex.Number)
                {
                    case 1:
                        MessageBox.Show("Error attempting to insert duplicate data.");
                        break;
                    case 12560:
                        MessageBox.Show("The database is unavailable.");
                        break;
                    default:
                        MessageBox.Show("Database error: " + ex.Message.ToString());
                        break;
                }
            }catch(System.Windows.Markup.XamlParseException xe)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("oops");
            }
            catch (System.InvalidOperationException ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message.ToString());
            }
            finally
            {
               // conn.Dispose();
            }

        }

        private void update_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            da.Update(dg.Tables[1]);
            MessageBox.Show("updated...");
        }
```

Comment: Instead of posting your database connection code, you should show us what you already tried to do with your data grid.

Comment: I am just curious about .Tables[1];  It seems you only have one table so I would have thought .Tables[0] but I guess it is working.

Comment: i tried Table[0] but it was throwing System.Windows.Markup.XamlParseException so randomly i tried Table[1] and it worked.

Comment: @gnud this is what i tried....rest are xaml